# Specifically designed Jordan basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be any complex $n\times n$ matrix. Can I then find a Jordan basis
$$
B_1\cup\ldots\cup B_r
$$
for $A$ with $B_k = \{b_1^k,\ldots,b_{n_k}^k\}$ ($b_{n_k}^k$ being an eigenvector of $A$ w.r.t. to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$) such that
$$
(A^*- \overline{\lambda_k})b_1^k = 0
$$
for each $k=1,\ldots,r$? I figured out that the answer is yes if $k=1$, but I doubt it when there is more than one Jordan chain. Can anyone help?

Comment: If $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then this would be a basis simultaneously diagonalizing $A$ and $A^\ast$, right? But that's impossible, since $A$ and $A^\ast$ don't commute usually.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simple. I should definitely take a break...